# sql query case dateadd

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I use GetDate and DateAdd in a SQL Query Select Case statement? Part of my query is as follows but it only returns OVER60 as the result regardless of client's Date of Birth.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I'm a novice at this and it's my first question to Stack Overflow so I thank you for any insight.

```
SELECT  G.ClientID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ClientDob, 101) AS ClientDob
, CASE 
        WHEN (G.ClientDob > GETDATE() AND G.ClientDob < dateadd(year, -13, GetDate()))THEN 'Under13' 
        WHEN (G.ClientDob >= DATEADD(YEAR, -13, GETDATE()) AND G.ClientDob < DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()))THEN '13-19'
        WHEN (G.ClientDob >= DATEADD(Year, -20, GETDATE()) AND G.ClientDob < DATEADD(Year, -30, GETDATE())) THEN '20-29'
        WHEN (G.ClientDob >= DATEADD(YEAR, -30, GETDATE()) AND G.ClientDob < DATEADD(YEAR, -45, GETDATE())) THEN '30-44'
        WHEN (G.ClientDob >= DATEADD(Year, -45, GETDATE()) AND G.ClientDob < DATEADD(YEAR, -60, GETDATE())) THEN '45-59'
        Else 'OVER60' 
END AS AgeCategory
```

Comment: are you sure that it is mysql? maybe ms sql server?

Comment: shouldn't `G.ClientDob < dateadd(year, -13, GetDate()))` be `G.ClientDob > dateadd(year, -13, GetDate()))`  dob 1/1/2014 < 12/30/2014 yes.  1/1/2014 < (1/1/2014-13) No...  so now none are true thus over60.  Simply put logic error < needs to be > on second eval.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I think you've got the > and < backwards.

Comment: Oh my gosh - DOH!  I can't believe I got that backwards.  THANK YOU for all the responses!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server despite `MySQL` tag
This should do it:

```
SELECT  G.ClientID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ClientDob, 101) AS ClientDob
, CASE 
    WHEN (G.ClientDob > dateadd(year, -13, GetDate()))THEN 'Under13' 
    WHEN (G.ClientDob > DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()))THEN '13-19'
    WHEN (G.ClientDob > DATEADD(Year, -30, GETDATE())) THEN '20-29'
    WHEN (G.ClientDob > DATEADD(YEAR, -45, GETDATE())) THEN '30-44'
    WHEN (G.ClientDob > DATEADD(YEAR, -60, GETDATE())) THEN '45-59'
    Else 'OVER60' 
END AS AgeCategory
```

You had `<` and `>` confusion, also there's no need for negating prior criteria in subsequent `WHEN` criteria, the first matching criteria gets used and none others are evaluated.

Note: As xQbert noted, the above assumes no future birthdates exist, if future birthdays can exist in your data (they shouldn't be allowed imo), you would want to handle those explicitly.

Comment: This misses an element. People with future birth dates fall into other in OP example, likely wrong.  This they will fall into under13.  Likely need to clarify if they belong in the results at all

Comment: @xQbert good point, added note.  Future birthdates shouldn't be permitted imo, but we can't always control what data we end up with.

Comment: Yeah I would agree with you that data shouldn't exist.. how could one have a date of birth in the future, it's not "fact" yet.  but since the OP explicitly had this case handled, we probably need to clarify.